# Are there any issues in parsing php within .html extension

Tags: php, html

I've just set-up my server to allow php to be parsed within .html extension. This all works fine but, are there any reasons why I should not do this? There is lot's of documentation about how to set it up but, none of them go into any detail as to whether it's a good/bad thing or makes absolutely no difference.

I could just create php pages but I'll be using such a small amount of php code (header, menu, footer include) that I don't really see the point. I've heard that parsing html pages as php can be a little slower, if so, how much slower, and is it significant enough of a problem to be concerned about.

Thanks, Jonny

Comment: There's nothing to worry about. The file extension is basically just something that faces the end user. If you don't want your users to know you're using PHP on the back end, you can hide it with a `.html` extension. You could also rewrite the URLs to show no extension at all to your users.  If there is any performance difference, it is likely to be so negligible that it wouldn't matter unless you were running massive traffic like Facebook or Flickr

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that's interesting. I have considered re-writing urls, although again I've heard concerns that this can impact google rankings, SEO and so on. I'm assuming however if these changes are made at the server level, htaccess that this isn't the case?

Comment: In my experience URL rewriting is usually done to _benefit_ search rankings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PHP is smart enough not to parse the part of the code that is not PHP.

But you may hit other problems instead, such as:

- lower maintainability (eg. you will need to look into the code to see what language is that),
- if you ever miss `.htaccess` (or other place where you define `.html` files as PHP scripts), you will expose your server-side code,
- you may miss the fact that your `.html` files contain PHP, after you look at your site some time later,
- etc.

Comment: Yeah fair points. Exposing PHP scripts is certainly an important one, I wouldn't be too concerned for this project but I can see how this could be a major issue.

Comment: Maintainability is a good point, esp. if you are not the only developer.

Answer (score 1):

> I could just create php pages but I'll be using such a small amount of php code (header, menu, footer include) that I don't really see the point.

Given that `.php` is one fewer letter to type than `.html` (and that's really the only difference involved in creating the two file types), and that making `.html` parsed by PHP requires more server configuration than the default setups, I don't see the point of overcomplicating things.

A file with HTML and parsed `<?php ?>` blocks is a PHP file, regardless of what extension you pop on it.

Comment: Yes I don't really disagree with what your saying here to be honest. I'm just intrigued to know more than anything. For the project I'm working on at the moment, it does not really make any difference what I use but it does look like there is very little to worry about if you ever did have to parse PHP within .html extension.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that all .html files will be examined by the PHP engine, rather than just having your web server (i.e. Apache) just serve them up. In high traffic situations, this might make a difference of having PHP have to take a quick glance at your code before moving on since there's nothing to parse, but in most cases the effect is negligible anyway. I don't think there's much problem with this at all, other than having a file extension available for you to sort the two out visually. ;)